# focus input text inside template-if in Polymer Dart

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

Let's assume I've got Polymer custom control like:

```
<template if="{{editMode}}">
 <input id="myInput" type="text">
</template>

<div on-doubleclick="{{setEditModeToTrue}}">
  some stuff here
</div>
```

Now I want **#myInput** to be text focused everytime editMode is true. The problem is that in the ***setEditModeToTrue*** handler #myInput is not yet in DOM tree so I **can't** focus it by:

```
root.QuerySelector('#myInput').focus();
```

(And yes I tried setting ***autofocus*** attribute on input but it works only for the first double click)

Is there any event or something else letting me know that template-if content is in DOM tree ?

Comment: ok my current work around is to do:


  new Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
        root.querySelector('#myInput').focus();
      });


in setEditModeToTrue handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap or extend the `input` element and put your code in the `attached` or `ready` lifecycle method or use MutationObserver.